# Problem with running 'next_batch' on tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Good day. I am trying to run an example for CNN on tensorflow on MNIST dataset as part of introduction as a newbie to tensorflow. I have had to use 'import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf' to enable use of the session call function used in example. However I have run into some trouble at the end of the following bit of code and cannot  get past it (showing full code here).

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import keras 

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

# Weight tensor
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10],tf.float32))
# Bias tensor
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10],tf.float32))

# run the op initialize_all_variables using an interactive session
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# mathematical operation to add weights and biases to the inputs
tf.matmul(x,W) + b

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

mnist_data, info = tfds.load("mnist", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train, test = mnist_data["train"], mnist_data["test"]

#Load 50 training examples for each training iteration   
import keras
for i in range(1000):
    batch = train.next_batch(50)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

### and I get the ffg. error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2 import keras
3 for i in range(1000):
----> 4     batch = train.next_batch(50)
5     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'next_batch'

I have seen various responses on StackOverflow in addressing this, such as writing your own call function for next_batch such:

```
def next_batch(num, data,labels):
'''
Return a total of `num` random samples and labels. 
'''
idx = np.arange(0 , len(data),len(labels))
np.random.shuffle(idx)
idx = idx[:num]
data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]

return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'next_batch'

I would greatly appreciate some guidance on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By far the "sanest" option IMHO is to ignore outdated tutorials and code in proper TF2 style; you will have a much better time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using TF2 with some semantics of TF1. In TF2, the `tf.data.API` also changed, and as far as I know, there is no compat.v1 option of this part of the API.

Since you use placeholders, you don't have the option of enabling eager execution. The only solution I see is to use the `as_dataframe` function from tensorflow_datasets. Here is how you could do it :

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

mnist_data, info = tfds.load("mnist", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_df = tfds.as_dataframe(mnist_data["train"],info)
batch_size = 50
for _,batch in train_df.groupby(np.arange(len(train_df))//batch_size):
    # Extracting images and flattening them
    x_inp = batch['image'].to_numpy()
    x_inp = np.stack(x_inp, axis=0)
    x_inp = np.reshape(x_inp, (batch_size, 28*28))
    # One hot encoding of the labels
    y_inp = batch['label'].to_numpy()
    one_hot = np.zeros((y_inp.size, 10))
    one_hot[np.arange(y_inp.size),y_inp] = 1
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_inp, y_: one_hot})
```

You could also try to migrate the code from tf1 to tf2, by following the guide : [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

Comment: without eager execution, on   x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10]) , i get the following error:  RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.

Comment: @Sivan I overlooked the fact that you are using placeholders. Unfortunately, eager execution won't work in that case. I also made the answer fit better your code since my previous answer was maybe too generic for your use case.

Comment: I must say that my experience on this platform has improved since the last time. Appreciate the support